# AWS Replication Agent installation failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disaster-recovery

I'm trying to install AWS Replication Agent on ubuntu20 server. As per document, I have created IAM user with below AWS managed policy.

> AWSElasticDisasterRecoveryAgentInstallationPolicy

> AWSElasticDisasterRecoveryAgentPolicy

When i tried to install agent on ubuntu20 server, I received Unexpected error and Installation failed even i attached Administrator full access policy.

```
Unexpected Error
Installation failed.
Learn more about installation issues in our documentation at 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/drs/latest/userguide/Troubleshooting-Agent-Issues.html
```

Can any one please let me know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Is that all of the output?

Comment: yes, When i run sudo python3 aws-replication-installer-init.py, its asked me to put region and access key. Then it thrown this error.